# Count function needs to include a where clause in an expression

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to make an expression in a specific table cell to generate a number of applications with a certain decision code. Here is the code:

```
=Count(Fields!APP_FKEY.Value) WHERE Fields!APP_DECISION_CODE.Value="3" OR Fields!APP_DECISION_CODE.Value="7")
```

Obviously this doesn't work but its essentially what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
=Count(IIf((Fields!APP_DECISION_CODE.Value="3" OR Fields!APP_DECISION_CODE.Value="7"), Fields!APP_FKEY.Value, Nothing))
```

or are you looking for the sum of `APP_FKEY.Value`?

```
=Sum(IIf((Fields!APP_DECISION_CODE.Value="3" OR Fields!APP_DECISION_CODE.Value="7"), Fields!APP_FKEY.Value, 0))
```